# logback.xml and running application from JetBrains IDEA IDE

Tags: intellij-idea, logback

When I develop application in IDEA, where should I place logback.xml for it to have an effect on the application?

It seems when you run/debug IDEA doesn't make any jars and doesn't invoke Maven to build something. Does it execute main() directly from compiled *.class file? If so, where can I put logback.xml so that it would have effect?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`logback.xml` should be available in the root directory of your CLASSPATH. When you run your application, the full CLASSPATH is printed at the very beginning. When I put `logback.xml` in `/src/main/resources` (Maven project) it works without any problem. Also putting it in `/src/test/resources` with `logback-test.xml` name has presence.

Simply run:

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/logback.xml");
```

And see whether it returns something or `null`.

If you are not working with Maven project, open *Project structure* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>) and add in *Modules* section select folder containing `logback.xml` and mark it as *Sources* (blue icon).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there a way to make Maven place logback.xml next to jar, not inside it?

Comment: By default, if you put any file in the same directory as the JAR, it won't be promoted to the CLASSPATH, so Logback won't see `logback.xml` there. But sure, just don't place it in `/src/main/resources` (and copy it manually where you want). If you want to have `logback.xml` outside to be able to change the configuration quickly, Logback supports reading environment properties out of the box amongst other possibilities.

Comment: Thanks for this it got me logging to Postgres! After I finally figured out my file was named backlog.xml and not logback.xml haha!

Comment: @tomasz: I want to load logback.xml from outside folder. This logback.xml will be common for two different projects running on tomcat6 and weblogic10. can you please suggest that how can I do this. straggling on web but not found any helpful solution :(

Comment: Although this reply is WAY too late for Sai, you can do specify the logback.xml path as a commandline parm: -Dlogback.configurationFile=/path/to/config.xml

Comment: getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("logback.xml"); without the / in front

Comment: @Todd thanks a lot. the commandline param you told works for me.

Comment: I have been searching for an answer to this for months. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to **re-build the project (not just re-run or re-compile the project)**.  Changing the `src\main\resources\logback.xml` did not affect logback because the class loader is picking up the logback.xml that is in the `target/` folder, not the `/src` folder.  This makes sense since target is the run environment.  Therefore, a build is required to transfer the new xml file over to target.