# How to make 3rd party application use logback.xml?

Tags: java, classpath, logback

I am working on a plugin for a Java application. This Java application does not use a real logger, however my plugin uses logback. When the end-user runs the application on Windows, he will run an .EXE file which somehow starts the application using several jars.

Now my problem is, that I don't know how to tell my plugin to find the logback.xml as I don't know what the classpath is set to and how I can modify it to include a path wher I put my logback.xml

Answer (score 1):

Try to put it into your jar (a plugin you did). Most likely you will end up with a solution from [logback.xml and running application from JetBrains IDEA IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612832/logback-xml-and-running-application-from-jetbrains-idea-ide).

Comment: I put my logback.xml in the src/main/resources folder of my maven project, but it wasn't found by the logger and the output was redirected to the console. Running "getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/logback.xml");" as suggested in your link, returns null. However, running getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("resources/logback.xml"); works. Is there something wrong with my maven project?

Comment: Can you post here output directory layout from your target. If in your case it works like this - then I think you launch your app from src/main via Main class, but not the jar.

Comment: I am not sure I understood what you are asking for, but inside my jar there are three folders: META-INF, org and resources.

Comment: Your `logback.xml` shouldn't be inside META-INF. If it is - you made an error in you maven project description.

Comment: So if it's in your resources folder in generated jar - your look up `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("resources/logback.xml")` is correct.

Comment: I see. But why is it not used and the logs appear in the console?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11200/discussion-between-artem-oboturov-and-se-norm)